# how to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin for RESTEasy preflight request?

Tags: cors, resteasy

server side code (my RESTEasy server is running on http://myServer):

preflight request handler:

```
@PermitAll
@OPTIONS
@Path("/uploadFile")
public Response preFlightUploadFile() throws Exception {
    logger.info("preFlightUploadFile");
    return Response.ok()
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, Cache-Control, content-type, x-requested-with")
            .build();
}
```

preflight response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myServer
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 16:16:16 GMT
```

Why the response is being over written?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Try using "http:/myServer" instead of * in access control allow origin

Comment: I have tried several things but it does not effect the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was some filter in myServer which was overwriting my settings..
I changed that and my code worked..